# Implementing a semaphore through a file

Tags: c, linux, binary-semaphore

thank you for taking your time to read this.
I'm trying to implement a semaphore through a file using C on a linux machine.

I have two process that I must synchronize, one has all the consonants of a file stored in an array, the other has all the vowels.
I've arranged these arrays so that if I alternate between them, I can reconstruct the original file and paste it in another file.
The issue now is making these two process alternate.
This exercise in particular wants me to implement a semaphore using a 3rd file.
What I've done is use the first byte of this file as a semaphore, lot loop one process until the other is finished.

I've tested with long sleep()s and yes, if these processes do alternate, the output file is exactly how I want it, but with that said, my current implementation of a semaphore seems not to be working.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
 
 
int main (){
    int child1=0, child2=0, fd, fd2, fs, i=0, i2=0;
    int count=0, count2=0;
    char buf1[20], buf2[20], a, b, con='1', vow='0', check1, check2;
    fd=open("text", O_RDONLY);
    fd2=open("text2", O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC,0777);
    fs=open("semaphore", O_RDWR, 0777);
 
 
    if (fork()==0)
        child1=1;
    else {
        if (fork()==0)
            child2=1;
    }
 
 
    //access vowel child
    if (child1){
        printf("I'm the first child\n");
        while ((read(fd,&a,1))==1){
            if (a=='a' || a=='e' || a=='i' || a=='o' || a=='u')
                buf1[count]=a;
            count++;
            }
        printf("count: %d\n", count);
        //vowels are now into buf1
        //wait for the brother to do the same
        sleep(2);
        for (i; i<=count+1; i++){
            if (buf1[i]!='\0'){
                printf("%c\n", buf1[i]);
                a=buf1[i];
                write(fd2,&a,1);
            }
            lseek(fs,0,SEEK_SET);
            write(fs,&con,1);//tell the semaphore it's the consonant's turn (1)         
            while(check1=='1'){
                lseek(fs,0,SEEK_SET);
                read(fs,&a,1);
                check1=a;
                sleep(1);
            } //get stuck until it's  somebody's else turn
        }
    }   
 
 
 
    //access consonant child
    else if (child2){
        sleep(1);
        lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);
        printf ("I'm the second child\n");
        while ((read(fd,&a,1))==1){
            if (a=='a' || a=='e' || a=='i' || a=='o' || a=='u')
                ;
            else
                buf2[count2]=a;
            count2++;
        }
        //resync
        sleep(1);
        printf("count: %d\n", count2);
        //consonants are now into buf1
 
        for (i; i<=count2+1; i++){
            lseek(fs,0,SEEK_SET);
            if (buf2[i]!='\0'){
                printf("%c\n", buf2[i]);
                b=buf2[i];
                write(fd2,&b,1);
            } //wait for vowel
            while(check2=='0'){
                lseek(fs,0,SEEK_SET);
                read(fs,&b,1);
                check2=b;
                sleep(1);
            }
            lseek(fs,0,SEEK_SET);
            write(fs,&vow,1);//tell the semaphore it's the vowel's turn (0)
        }
    }
 
 
 
 
 
    else
        printf("I'm the father\n");
    sleep(10);
    exit(0);
}
```

The file "text" has "hello world" stored in it. What happens when I execute this code is that what's copy and pasted is "hll wrld eoo". What exactly am I doing wrong with my semaphore?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to implement acquire/release similar to `pthread_mutex_t` or `sem_t`.

You need *two* functions:

1. `acquire` to wait for and acquire ownership
2. `release` to release ownership and grant it to the "other" process

You're conflating the two operations into one. And, your code doesn't actually do locking properly.

*Side note:* You are creating "zombie" processes because the father does *not* do `wait` on the children.

Here's some refactored code.

I added `acquire` and `release` calls to the places where you had your sempahore code (e.g. the second loops for each child). But, you *might* need them in the first loops as well (which I did *not* do).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void
acquire(int fs,char iam)
{
    char own;

    while (1) {
        lseek(fs,0,SEEK_SET);
        read(fs,&own,1);

        if (own == iam)
            break;

        usleep(1);
    }
}

void
release(int fs,char iam)
{
    char other;

    if (iam == 1)
        other = 2;
    else
        other = 1;

    lseek(fs,0,SEEK_SET);
    write(fs,&other,1);
}

int
main()
{
    int child1 = 0,
        child2 = 0,
        fd,
        fd2,
        fs,
        i = 0,
        i2 = 0;
    int count = 0,
        count2 = 0;
    char buf1[20],
     buf2[20],
     a,
     b,
     con = '1',
        vow = '0',
        check1,
        check2;

    fd = open("text", O_RDONLY);
    fd2 = open("text2", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, 0777);

    fs = open("semaphore", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777);

    // initialize semaphore to grant access to one or the other
    buf1[0] = 1;
    write(fs,buf1,1);

    if (fork() == 0)
        child1 = 1;
    else {
        if (fork() == 0)
            child2 = 1;
    }

    // access vowel child
    if (child1) {
        printf("I'm the first child\n");
        while ((read(fd, &a, 1)) == 1) {
            if (a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u')
                buf1[count] = a;
            count++;
        }
        printf("count: %d\n", count);
        // vowels are now into buf1
        // wait for the brother to do the same
        sleep(2);
        for (i; i <= count + 1; i++) {
            acquire(fs,1);
            if (buf1[i] != '\0') {
                printf("%c\n", buf1[i]);
                a = buf1[i];
                write(fd2, &a, 1);
            }
            release(fs,1);
        }
    }

    // access consonant child
    else if (child2) {
        sleep(1);
        lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
        printf("I'm the second child\n");
        while ((read(fd, &a, 1)) == 1) {
            if (a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u');
            else
                buf2[count2] = a;
            count2++;
        }
        // resync
        sleep(1);
        printf("count: %d\n", count2);
        // consonants are now into buf1

        for (i; i <= count2 + 1; i++) {
            acquire(fs,2);
            if (buf2[i] != '\0') {
                printf("%c\n", buf2[i]);
                b = buf2[i];
                write(fd2, &b, 1);
            }                           // wait for vowel
            release(fs,2);
        }
    }

    else {
        printf("I'm the father\n");
        while (wait(NULL) >= 0);
        printf("all done\n");
    }

    //sleep(10);
    exit(0);
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The two child processes share a common file position for the semaphore file because the `open` call is done in the parent.

So, there is a potential race condition between the `lseek` and the `read` or `write`.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Have each child open the semaphore file *after* the `fork`. Then, they do *not* share the file position.
2. Instead of `lseek` followed by `read` or `write`, use `pread` or `pwrite`.

Here is the latter:

```
void
acquire(int fs,char iam)
{
    char own;

    while (1) {
        pread(fs,&own,1,0);

        if (own == iam)
            break;

        usleep(1);
    }
}

void
release(int fs,char iam)
{
    char other;

    if (iam == 1)
        other = 2;
    else
        other = 1;

    pwrite(fs,&other,1,0);
}
```